# is there a library that scan Ids or any type of identity documentation or letters recognition?

Tags: android, camera

//is there a library that scan Ids or any type of identity documentation //or letters recognition ?

Answer (score 1):

For ID scanning you can try Jumio: https://www.jumio.com/netverify/ . It's very good, recognises faces, validates scanned data and supports broad range of docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a Computer:

http://www.cssn-developers.com/documents.htm

Otherwise, if you want to "scan" a ID with the camera of an android device and want to get the name of the person, [OpenCV-Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) is often used

Comment: I've already experience with OpenCV and it's really very good!

Comment: still didn't try it i ll tell you when i do Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For letter recognition, the technology you are looking for is called OCR - optical character recognition. So searching for android ocr library might help. See [this library](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try [iDenfy identity verification company](https://www.idenfy.com) which provide identity document (ID) recognition, data extraction (OCR) and faked document detection.